# Sencha Architect: Build a tree

Tags: extjs, tree, treenode, sencha-architect

How can I build a **tree** ins **Sencha Architect**? All what I found online was concerned with editing the code which is read-only in my case. What can I do about that?

Please help! I would really appreciate it because I've been having a hard time figuring it out.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

1. Add a `TreeStore` with the config specified below*
2. Add a `TreePanel` with {store: 'TreeStore', rootVisible: false}

*

```
fields: [{
    name: 'text'
}],
//please note that you need to wrap the root config inside an object {}
root: {
    expanded: true,
    children: [
            { text: "detention", leaf: true },
            { text: "homework", expanded: true, children: [
                { text: "book report", leaf: true },
                { text: "algebra", leaf: true}
            ] },
            { text: "buy lottery tickets", leaf: true }
    ]
}
```

**Edit1:**
Press this GREEN icon to edit the root config.
[image: Edit mode]

Comment: i can't add the code because the code is read-only, how can I work around that?
And should I add a model for the TreeStore, or no need for that?

Comment: Only add one field. That is a simplified model. Do you have permissions to edit code?

Comment: no I can't edit the code.. it's read-only; I can't cut, paste or add anything